# How to say "I can read that book in one day" (stressing one)

Tags: article, numbers

Do we just say

> Ich kann das Buch an einem Tag lesen.

?
It sounds like

> I can read the book in any one day. (or someday)

But if I want to stress that

> I can read the book in **ONE** day (not two days or more).

How should I say it? Isn't there any grammar expressing the stress on *one*?   For example,

> Ich kann das Buch in ein Tag lesen?

Comment: The question is, are you speaking about emphasis in a written text or are you speaking about emphasis in oral communication? Solutions will differ.

Comment: While the answers are valid, *an einem Tag* does **not** sound like *any one day*.

Comment: One way to say it is the same way you say it in English: "Ich kann das Buch an **einem** Tag lesen!" ;-) That is, you stress the "einem". Ah yes, Christian has a point: This will only work when spoken (or when italics/bold are available ;-)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### [in](https://dwds.de/wb/in)

The shortest variant would be using the temporal preposition *in* instead of *an*, as you already found out. In this usage *in* already implies that something happens within the time span further specified. It should therefore be clear that a single day only is needed.

> Ich kann das Buch **in** einem Tag lesen.
> *I can read that Book **within** a day*

<sup>There is some ambiguity with *in* as it can also mean *after a day*, however context should make that clear, and most people would then say ***erst** in einem Tag*.</sup>

#### [nur](https://dwds.de/wb/nur)

This is also a good use case for the tiny but powerful adverb *nur* if we want to further stress the fact that is was only just a single day.

> Ich kann das Buch in **nur** einem Tag lesen.
> *I can read that book in **just** one day.*

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind ogf answer I was looking for! The difference between in and an!

Comment: note that - though unlikely in this context - it is possible to misunderstand the "in" variant. It could ALSO mean "I can read this book one day from now"

Comment: @Syndic: good point - I believe most people would then say ***erst** in einem Tag* but if they don't it may be ambiguous indeed. Context for the rescue :)

Comment: Or for further pointing out the one day: Ich brauche nur einen Tag, um das Buch zu lesen.

Comment: @Zibelas: correct, *nur* is such a magical word here :)

Comment: Even better with more emphasis: "Ich kann das **ganze** Buch in nur einem Tag lesen" -- *I can read the whole book in a single day.*

Comment: "Ich kann das Buch an einem Tag **aus**lesen" or "Ich kann das Buch **innerhalb eines Tages** lesen" would be versions that would be well understood.

Answer (score 40):

To stress *one day* you can say

> Ich kann das Buch an einem **einzigen** Tag lesen.

Comment: In english that would translate to the meaning of "I can read the book in a single day". I think that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I understand, but my hope was to not use any additional word that clarifies it.

Answer (score 18):

With

> Ich kann das Buch an einem Tag lesen.

you already express that you can read the whole book within one day. Depending on the context there might be rare cases where you want to eliminate any doubt.
Possibilities are:

Adding *komplett*:

> Ich kann das *komplette* Buch an einem Tag lesen.

You could also use *durchlesen*:

> Ich kann das Buch an einem Tag durchlesen.

Comment: *durchlesen* has the connotation of browsing, skimming. *auslesen*, *ganz lesen* would be a better fit for the third example.

Comment: There might be some regional differences but Duden.de describes *durchlesen* with "von Anfang bis Ende, ganz lesen"

Comment: maybe nitpicking - I just tried to imagine its use in everyday speech and I think it is the wrong use case: *Dieses Buch schenke ich dir zum Geburtstag. Aber nicht wieder gleich in einem Tag durchlesen* or rather *... nicht wieder gleich in einem Tag auslesen*, the first one just does not come naturally.

Comment: I see, in your sentence it seems wrong. But for example in: "Ich habe das Buch durchgelesen, Obama kommt darin nicht vor" it seems perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 12):

If your translation doesn't have to be close to the original, I would say something like:

> Das Buch schaffe ich an einem Tag.

Or:

> Für das Buch brauche ich keinen Tag.

Comment: These sound a lot more colloquial than the other ones. As a native German speaker in an informal conversation, I would most likely use one of these!

Comment: Doesn't "Das Buch schaffe ich `an` einem Tag." sound like "I will read the book someday."? Isn't it better to say "Das Buch schaffe ich `in` einem Tag." to stress 1 day (not 2 days)? I'm really curious.

Comment: @Falco: Yes, it is clearly colloquial. When you say it, you risk being perceived as arrogant (e.g., when you say that to a professor referring to Kant's *Kritik der praktischen Vernunft*)

Comment: @ChanKim Not in this case. "an" sounds a lot more natural combined with a completing action. While "Das schaffe ich in einer Stunde" is normal. - with a single day "an" sounds a lot more natural than "in" and the meaning is unmistakenly clear with "schaffe"

Comment: @Chan Kim: Yes. But the OP's “I can read that book in one day” is also purely hypothetical. If I say "in", it sounds indeed more like a promise that I will have read the book by tomorrow at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

Or, for a more colloquial version:

> Das Buch hab ich doch in einem Tag durch.

Which is more or less

> I'll be through with that book within a day.

Answer (score 4):

One of the shortest possibilities:

> Das Buch kostet mich [höchstens] einen Tag.

Comment: Ich kann's noch kürzer: **"Das Buch? Ein Tag!"**

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Gratulation, fetter gehts nicht.

Comment: @Pollitzer ***KLAR GEHT'S FETTER!!!1!***